# Inadvertent clickjacking on page causes LastPass login dialog to appear.

Tags: password-management, lastpass

I like the idea of password managers but have become leery of the way they interact with browsers (especially given [the recent "LostPass" exploit](https://archive.org/details/Lostpass#)).

Today I found that viewing a certain page with "Prominently highlight unhidden fields" in Burp, the page munging caused some UI redressing that made the LastPass login appear when clicking other links on the page (in addtion to when clicking on the asterisk in the password box.  It made me think I was being attacked.

Central question is:  what could a malicious or infected site do with this ability to launch the LastPass dialog?

Here is a screenshot showing the dialog appearing after clicking on the sunglasses link:
[image: LastPass dialog appears when clicking the link under the sunglasses]

Answer (score 1):

A basic phishing attack springs to mind.

However, a malicious site could of course construct a LastPass login box themselves and hope the user uses it to login.

I suppose the advantage here is that the LastPass box will only appear if the LastPass extension is installed, plus it may have the advantage of always being current and that of the username being pre-filled in because it is from the actual LastPass dialog generation code.

It is difficult to answer further without seeing a full POC in action.